# Heroku doesnt run my python app but app working well locally

Tags: python, heroku, discord

I created a DC RP using [these source codes](https://github.com/Ju0x/discord-richpresence-example/blob/main/example.py), it runs fine on local. But I am getting the following errors on Heroku.

Errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/main.py", line 5, in <module>s-rp...
    rpc.connect()  # RP burada bağlanmaya başlar.
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pypresence/presence.py", line 43, in connect
    self.loop.run_until_complete(self.handshake())
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 642, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pypresence/baseclient.py", line 128, in handshake
    self.sock_reader, self.sock_writer = await asyncio.open_unix_connection(self.ipc_path, loop=self.loop)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/asyncio/streams.py", line 111, in open_unix_connection
    transport, _ = await loop.create_unix_connection(
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/asyncio/unix_events.py", line 244, in create_unix_connection
    await self.sock_connect(sock, path)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 502, in sock_connect
    return await fut
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 507, in _sock_connect
    sock.connect(address)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

requirements.txt:

```
discord
pypresence
```

runtime.txt: `python-3.9.1`

Comment: Do you have a `Procfile`? Do you have all buildpacks you need on heroku? Are you including all the packages in your `requirements.txt` that your program needs?

Comment: @AdityaTomar yes i have, also i tried same app on my ubuntu server but i got same error...

Comment: refer to [this video](https://youtu.be/BPvg9bndP1U) to get a full walkthrough on how to set up your bot on Heroku. Keep in mind that at timestamp 6:36, he puts `git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py@rewrite` in his `requirements.txt` file. However, that should be replaced by `git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py`, which is the correct version of the git repository. Follow all the instructions in the video and you should be able to set it up properly- it worked for me. Good luck!

Comment: @AdityaTomar he's talking about [RPC](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/rpc) (also see my answer) not about Discord Bots.

Comment: Oh, I see. My bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/rpc

> All Discord clients have an RPC server running on localhost that allows control over local Discord clients.

You **have to** run it locally. That's how Discord RPC works.
Your Discord client provides a running RPC server which the Discord Rich Presence is connecting to. You are merely running the Discord Rich Presence without a Discord client present. That Discord client is based on your user account and not a bot account.

If you manage to run the Discord Client remotely on a server, then you can run Discord RPC remotely as well. (Basically you install Discord Client on a Desktop version VPS and login in to the Client as normal.)
Heroku is not suited for this task since it is headless.